# Regex.IsMatch clarification

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match a whole word againt a string.  I have been having an issue when I wanted to restrict the matches to whole words only.  When I trying looking into it I found I had a greater issue with my understanding.

The following program does not find a match, I was expecting it to:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch("t1", "\bt1\b"))
        {
            return;  // I was expecting this to be hit but it is not
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `\b`

Use `\\` to escape it or just use `@` verbatim.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("t1", @"\bt1\b"))
{
    return;  //This works as expected
}
```

Here's the [Demo](http://ideone.com/C1eCDd)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is working. You just need replace each **"\"** symbol to **"\\"** or add **@** before regex pattern to tell the compiller that your string is literal (**@"your regex"**).

Answer (score 1):

You can test .Net regular expressions here:

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

It gives you the string literal to use in programs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you forgot to add @ symbol in front of "\bt1\b" or you can also use "\\bt1\\b" in code.
So your code should be

```
Regex.IsMatch("t1", @"\bt1\b");
```

or

```
Regex.IsMatch("t1", "\\bt1\\b");
```

Escape sequence misplaced.